# Custom Master Pages in WSS3.0 / SharePoint 2007 DOC TYPE

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, master-pages, wss

I have a custom master page that I use in WSS3.0 (SharePoint 2007) and I am using a HTML 'DOC TYPE' which I am declaring at the top of the master page.  The site all works very well with my master page apart from some of SharePoint controls which are acting a little funny, namely the People Picker for a People and Group field.

If I remove the DOC TYPE declaration then the People Picker and other controls work perfectly and behave as they should but it sends some of my customisations/layout all over.

Before I spend a lot of time reviewing fixing the issues I get to my design without having the DOC TYPE declared, does anyone know if there is a certain DOC TYPE that is compatible with WSS3.0 / SharePoint 2007 and all of its features (i.e. People Picker Fields)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heather Solomon (a super expert at SharePoint branding) has some sample SP2007 minimal master pages here: http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/BaseMasterPages.aspx and for them she uses DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional.

Comment: thanks for this, I reviewed the information on here and the fix was to add a META tag to the page to force the page to work in IE7 Mode which fixes the issues with the controls in WSS that have not been built (by Microsoft) to a standard.